# Creating multiple columns in a csv file and separating the single data to multiple columns using python

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I want to split a data separated by commas into different columns using python. How do i do it? I am new to python. [Have to split the data in this column to columns with different headings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRQ6Z.png)

Comment: If the data in the picture is really your data, it doesn't make much sense to read it in automatically, since it is quite unsorted and would need to be restructured manually anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import pandas as pd

import csv

xl = pd.read_csv("Name.csv")

df = pd.DataFrame(xl.Name.str.split(',',5).tolist(),columns = ['Name1','Value', 'Watt', 'Tolerance', 'Package', 'Type'])

df1 = pd.read_csv("Resistor.csv")

result = pd.concat([df1, df], axis=1, join_axes=[df1.index])

del result['Name']

result.to_csv('output.csv')